# jQuery dynamic main/sub category selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

- **First** - I'm trying to get the sub-category `.container` function to run separately for each instance of `post-item` but as you can
  see, only the first instance is handling the sub-categories.
- **Second** - I want one of the `sub-item` to be set under the `menu` item and to show its list of sub-category items when toggled.

Right now I set the item pre-selected `menu` to the sub-category `"comb"` which belongs to `cat1` of the main categories.

> ```
> <label class="sub-btn" for="comb">
> <input class="sub-input" id="comb" type="radio" name="radios" />
> </label>
> ```

I can't figure out how to connect it back to the main category and have it function as if it were a selection. The idea is to just display a pre-selected `sub-item` on the `menu` of each instance and the main category would automatically be set to reflect this as well as the `type-list` for the other `sub-items` in the same category would be able to be toggled on initial load (just like it does when you make a main category selection).

https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/rvdqgv

Comment: Your code is too dirty and Really I can not understand what you want to do. explain logic of this task.

Comment: Can you clarify your second point? When I click on the menu I see sub-categories.

Comment: @JonathanChaplin right now the sub menu opens but the other categories aren't there unless you click a main category first

Comment: You have a lot of mis-placed & un-closed html tags which are causing problems in your JS. Run your code through : https://validator.w3.org/ and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: The code isn't yet set up to function as asked in the question. I'm looking for an answer that helps determine how to arrange the code to do what I am asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is mainly here:

```
$(".container").on("change", ".sub-btn", function() {
  var t = $(this).closest(".sub-btn");
  $(".menu-text").text(t.find("span").text());
  var pathA = t.find("#patha").attr("d");
  $(".pathainitial").attr("d", pathA);
  var pathAc = t.find("#patha").attr("fill");
  $(".pathainitial").attr("fill", pathAc);
});
```

More specifically, `$(".menu-text")` and `$(".pathainitial")` which include *all* the matching elements regardless its container.

**UPDATE**

Here's the updated JS code (not the whole code, but just for the first and second points in the question):

```
// Switches the clicked item in `.type-list` with the active item in `.menu`.
$(".type-list").on("click", ".sub-input", function() {
  var t = $(this).closest(".sub-btn"),           // the currently clicked item
      m = t.closest('.type-list').prev('.menu'), // the currently active item
      i, i2, tt, mt, tdiv, mdiv, tcat, io;

  // For the currently clicked item.
  i = t.find('path:first-child');
  tt = t.find('.sub-icon > b');
  tdiv = t.parent('.sub-list');
  tcat = tdiv.attr('data-for');

  // For the currently active item.
  i2 = m.find('path:first-child');
  mt = m.find('.sub-icon > b');
  mdiv = m.children('.sub-item');
  // Save the attributes or text before we modify them.
  io = {
    d: i2.attr('d'),
    fill: i2.attr('fill'),
    text: mt.text(),
    cat: mdiv.attr('data-for')
  };

  mdiv.attr('data-for', tcat);
  mt.text(tt.text());
  i2.attr("d", i.attr('d'))
    .attr("fill", i.attr('fill'));

  tdiv.attr('data-for', io.cat);
  tt.text(io.text);
  i.attr('d', io.d)
    .attr('fill', io.fill);

  // Put the item in its own category.
  if (tcat !== io.cat) {
    tdiv.removeClass('active');
    tdiv.closest('.sub-item')
      .removeClass(tcat)
      .addClass(io.cat);
  }
});
```

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjNLdb

**Notes**

For each `.sub-icon`, the HTML should be:

```
<span class="sub-icon">
    <svg ...></svg><br>
    <b>Text here</b>
</span>
```

i.e. wrap the `Text here` in a `b` element.

And the `.sub-item` *in `.menu`* should have a `data-for` with the value being the active *category* key/`class` (e.g. `cat1`):

```
<div class="sub-item edit current" data-for="cat1">
    ...
</div>
```

And in the `.cat-dropdown-menu` *of the **pre-selected** category*, the `.cat-item` should have a `active` in its `class`; e.g.:

```
<label class="cat-item active" style="color:blue">
    ...
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Sally. I sent a chat with more information about the second point in the question. Hoping you have time to continue helping!

Comment: Sorry I missed (or didn't really get..) the second point. I've posted some replies there. Check it out and I'll update the JS soon.